# Javascript Validation issue with array

Tags: javascript

I have a lot of code here.. basically I wanted to convert my global variables into arrays... IE. the grade array. When I prompt for the grade (prompt) it is supposed to validate that the input is a number (via the if statements) and if it's not a valid number, ex. a letter, the program returns an alert("Not a valid input, please enter a valid input"). I don't understand where my code is wrong, but it KEEPS returning the alert message.

Here's the code:

```
 // Loop through assignments
    for(var k = 1; k <= numberOfAssignments; k++) {

        // Print the first <td>
        document.write(table.dataopen);

        // Get the grade for the assignment
        var grades = new Object();
        grades.validrange = 0;
        grades.min = 0;
        grades.max = 100;

        var grade = new Array();
        do {
            grade[grade.length] = prompt("What's the grade for assignment " + k + "?");

            var convertedInput = parseInt(grade[grade.length]);

            // Using automatic conversion, if the original input and the converted input are the same,
            // we know we have a valid integer.
            var result = convertedInput == grade[grade.length];

            // If not a valid integer, let's show an appropriate error message. We use alert as
            // we may change how we report errors back.
            if(!result) {
                alert("Not a valid input. Please try again");
            }

            // Note the use of paranthesis; the first three clauses have to be all TRUE in order for the value in
            // the paranthesis to be true. In this context, we first check that all values are indeed numbers.
            // Then we check whether the grade is less than the min or greather than the max
            if((!isNaN(grade[grade.length]) && !isNaN(grades.min) && !isNaN(grades.max)) &&
                grade[grade.length] < grades.min || grade[grade.length] > grades.max) {

                // Invalid range, so show the error.
                alert("Valid ranges are between " + grades.min + " and " + grades.max);

                grades.validrange = false;
            }
            else {
                // If we came here, it means we didn't use the previous return, which in turns mean that the three
                // arguments are numbers AND the range is valid

                grades.validrange = true;
            }

        } while(!result || !grades.validrange);

        var score = parseInt(grade[grade.length]);

        // Display the grade
        document.write(score);

        // Keep track of the grades/scores (add to total)
        totalScore += score;

        // Print the </td>
        document.write(table.dataclose);
    }
```

Comment: `var result = convertedInput == grade[grade.length];` what this line is supposed to?

Answer (score 2):

`grade[grade.length]` <~~ I thing here is the problem.

- `grade.push()` - add a new input message into grade.
- `grade[grade.length - 1]` - get last one

-

```
//...

grade.push(prompt("What's the grade for assignment " + k + "?"));
var lastIndex = grade.length - 1;

// Using automatic conversion, if the original input and the converted input are the same,
// we know we have a valid integer.
var convertedInput = parseInt(grade[lastIndex]);

//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem

```
grade[grade.length] = prompt("What's the grade for assignment " + k + "?");

var convertedInput = parseInt(grade[grade.length-1]);
```

Your first statement works fine. Assuming that your array has one element, `grade.length` will return 1 which will be the index of your next element. But in the second statement `grade.length` will be 2 and grade[2] is undefined as your array has only two elements(grade[0] & grade[1]). So your second statement should be

```
var convertedInput = parseInt(grade[grade.length-1]);
```

Comment: Thanks! Should I replace everything in the stance with grade[grade.length-1]? IE in this conditional:

  if((!isNaN(grade[grade.length]) && !isNaN(grades.min) && !isNaN(grades.max)) &&
                grade[grade.length] < grades.min || grade[grade.length] > grades.max)

Answer (score 0):

grade.length is 0 after initialization, then it becomes 1 after you add an element.
It should be:

```
var convertedInput = parseInt(grade[grade.length - 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `var result = isNaN(convertedInput)` if you want to check `parseInt` result

Comment: @Siddharth where do you see a link in my answer?